# How destroy a controller with ui-router in ionic framework

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

I have an ionic angular app, and I use the ui-router. My problem is that the controllers doesn't get destroyed when I navigate from their state to a new one. So when a user log out and an another log in they can see the first user data because the controllers still contain the data for the first user. How can I destroy the controllers on state change?

Here is an example config:

```
$stateProvider.state('root.module.view', {
  url: '/path',
  views: {
    'content@root': {
      template: require('./template.jade'),
      controller: 'MyController',
      controllerAs: 'myCtrl'
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: In angualrjs $scope's and controllers get destroyed and when visited to new page , Angular will call $destroy on lastScope (which means previous scope and controllers)

Comment: @shushanthp is right here... check where the data is coming from... is it coming from localStorage???

Comment: As far as I know its not true in my case, because of the ui-router, our controllers are binded to the routes not to the DOM elements. And simply navigating to a new page then navigation back wont cause the controller constructor to run again. (Because the route still exist)

Comment: Exactly. You should either force reload all the relevant routes or don't place user-specific stuff to controller constructors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I have found the answer, the root of the problem is that Ionic cache the views for faster page changes, but by doing so it prevents the destroyation of the controllers on page leave.

There is more way to change this behaviour. Firstly you can set the `cache` attribute in the route config like this:

```
$stateProvider.state('root.module.view', {
  url: '/path',
  views: {
    'content@root': {
      cache: false,
      template: require('./template.jade'),
      controller: 'MyController',
      controllerAs: 'myCtrl'
    }
  }
});
```

Or you can entirely disabling it with the `$ionicConfigProvider` this way:

```
  $ionicConfigProvider.views.maxCache(0);
```

The third option is to use the attribute:

```
<ion-view cache-view="false" view-title="My Title!">
...
</ion-view>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this in your controller,

```
function NewsHomeController($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess',
            function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){ 
                //do stuff here.
            });
}
```

you can do your logic when that event triggers.

if you really want to trigger some things when scope gets destroyed,

```
$scope.$on('destroy', function () {
    // do something here
});
```

you can try this, but I think this is more appropriate for directive controllers.

Comment: And how can I destroy my controller there? I can see it names in the fromState object but how can I destroy it?

Comment: You can't just destroy a controller.  here I update the code above.

Comment: Ahh, yeah but adding this code to every controller is not really an option. Is there any way to get a controller scope by its name? Because then I have to listen only in one place for the statechange

Comment: you can just have a main directive or controller for your app, and just listen there.

Comment: Yes, but how can I destroy a controller knowing only its name?

Comment: you know, you can do everybody a favor, especially yourself, and read some angular docs.  even if you make this work, you have no idea how angular really works.  I recommend you try to understand the innerworkings first.

Comment: Thanks, for contributing to my problem. Really, do me a favor tell me how it works. Or first start to write normal answers, because u just throw something in here hoping I will accept it as an answer.  (Btw an answer what I already tried, I gave an another shot to it because I thought maybe you can contribute something new to my problem. But seems u cant. Just judging if the asker ask instead of just giving u the mark.)